# nginx ingress annotations to redirect to authentication and get back headers

Tags: redirect, nginx, auth-request

I've the below nginx conf file to redirect all the requests (by default) to /auth (of my service) and then get back a response header (foo_id). This header will be forwarded to the original request URI triggered by user. The below works properly with the nginx.
...

```
location / 
{
    auth_request /auth;
    auth_request_set $foo_id $upstream_http_foo_id;
    proxy_pass    $request_uri
    proxy_set_header X-foo-Token $foo_id;
    root   html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

location /auth 
{
    internal;
    proxy_pass   https://myhost/myservice;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
```

---

But I need the corresponding ingress rules/annotations that are required to achieve the above use case. I couldn't get the respective auth/proxy-pass related annotations. Kindly help out.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Nginx Ingress Annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#external-authentication) to achieve this goal.

In nutshell:

Assuming, you have an external auth service, which has a Kubernetes service configured.
You need an annotation, which sends auth requests to this service:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: http://auth-service.<NameSpace>.svc.cluster.local/auth
```

Also, you can use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-snippet` annotation to set your custom configuration for the auth request e.g.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-snippet: |
    auth_request_set $foo_id $upstream_http_foo_id;
    proxy_pass    $request_uri
    proxy_set_header X-foo-Token $foo_id;
```

If you need to return some headers on successful auth, you can use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers`:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers:  X-Auth
```

And, `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin` to specify the custom error page

Comment: Hi, is there any way for me to specify which URL that I want to exclude the external auth from using the `auth-snippet`?

Comment: @felixbmmm You could define that URL in a separate Ingress. There does not seem to be another way.